# uWSGI return old data

Tags: python, django, caching, tastypie, uwsgi

I have the REST application (django+tastypie). Some resources must return data related by current time. For example:

I'd get the banner list from url
`/api/banners`

My API return only banners active for current time `(date_active_start__lte=datetime.now(), date_active_end__gte=datetime.now())`
When one banner must be showed or hidden, result data doesn't change until uwsgi restart

```
#mysite_uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /var/www/project
module          = mysite.wsgi:application
home            = /var/www/python
master          = true
processes       = 5
socket          = /var/www/mysite.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
uid             = www-data
gid             = www-data
vacuum          = true
# touch-reload    = /var/www/mysite_uwsgi.ini
pidfile         = /var/www/pid.file
```

Comment: can you provide the tastypie Resource of this api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems related to using a method instead of the bound method.

Try removing the method calling to: `(date_active_start__lte=datetime.now, date_active_end__gte=datetime.now)`

If you provide the full Resource I could take a deep look into it, but I had similar issues due to using the method where I should use the bound method.

Comment: Thanks @silvio. Your drive me to idea! In my code I filtered queryset in Meta-class. After moving in get_object_list all was well!